# How do I configure a Less file watcher's output directory?

Tags: phpstorm

How do I configure a less file watcher to put the output css file into the same directory as the less file, rather than in a 'css' folder in the parent directory.

I've read the help here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/using-file-watchers.html, but I cannot workout how to configure this?

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following:

```
Arguments: --no-color $FileName$ $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
Working directory: $FileDir$
Output paths to refresh: $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

.css file will be created in the same directory as .less file